# What does false do in aot build angular cli - Out of memory issue

Tags: angular, build

What `"false"` do  in `ng build --prod --aot false` command

I am working on an angular 4 app developed with ng cli, as it is a enterprise solution the app becomes so huge that it takes too much time to serve and build. I even got javascript out of memory issues and the I started using following command to build the app

```
ng build --prod --aot false
```

But I am not sure how it works

Comment: where did you see it?

Comment: I saw it in one of the stackoverflow threads , if I run command without false it gives me out of memory error so definitely it has some impact

Comment: There is nothing interesting here you just switch off ahead of time compilation

Comment: @yurzui, good to know. so it's basically a value for `--aot` option? the opposite would be `--aot true`?

Comment: If we use `--prod` we already have `--aot true` There is a great link about this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Comment: I would advice not to disable aot but rather run cli by using `node --max_old_space_size...`

Comment: @yurzui, cool, thanks. I'm wondering if it would work with `--aot=true`. I think you should put it as answer

Comment: @yurzui It means --prod and --prod --aot should have same output but I noticed that there is a size difference of dist folder and may file count also.

Comment: @yurzui it will be good if you can answer it with guidelines to use node --max_old_space_size because I find it hard to use space size command for cli and aot build

Comment: `but I noticed that there is a size difference of dist folder` Please reproduce it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All available commands for angular-cli can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/1.4.x/packages/@angular/cli/commands).

Now, when we run `ng build --prod` it means that we specify [target](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1.4.x/packages/%40angular/cli/commands/build.ts#L17-L23) for our application:

```
{
    name: 'target',
    type: String,
    default: 'development',
    aliases: ['t', { 'dev': 'development' }, { 'prod': 'production' }],
    description: 'Defines the build target.'
},
```

then angular-cli [sets default options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1.4.x/packages/%40angular/cli/models/webpack-config.ts#L84-L102)(*angular-cli@1.4.x*) based on specified target:

```typescript
// Fill in defaults for build targets
public addTargetDefaults(buildOptions: T): T {
  const targetDefaults: { [target: string]: Partial<BuildOptions> } = {
    development: {
      environment: 'dev',
      outputHashing: 'media',
      sourcemaps: true,
      extractCss: false,
      namedChunks: true,
      aot: false
    },
    production: {
      environment: 'prod',
      outputHashing: 'all',
      sourcemaps: false,
      extractCss: true,
      namedChunks: false,
      aot: true
    }
  };
```

that can also be found in [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/1.4.x/docs/documentation/build.md#--dev-vs---prod-builds)

When you add `--aot false` you override default `aot` option. So it becomes `false`.

If you have some problem with aot building then there is [some thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618) for that where the common solution is running build like:

**package.json**

```typescript
"scripts": {
  "prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod" 
}
```

but besides above i prefer doing some refactoring code to reduce application size and help aot compiler to be executed faster.

Answer (score 7):

AOT is  by default true for production builds, if you want to deactivate is you can use:

```
ng build prod --no-aot
```

or

```
ng build prod --aot=false
```

but using AOT will compile your templates to js before serving them, so the browser will load them very fast